# Recreating the iOS 5 Mail.app sidebar (iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad

iOS 5's Mail app has a nifty little swipe gesture that brings up the sidebar in portrait mode. Now it seems like that gesture would be useful in other apps that use the master/detail layout, but as far as I can tell Apple hasn't released any sample code or documentation to show how the effect was created.

I've thought about how to replicate the effect in my own app but I'm not super experienced in view programming. Has anyone managed to recreate this effect in their own apps or would anyone know how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a downloadable project that pretty well reverse engineers everything the Mail app is doing with its split view interface: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-4-Book-Examples/blob/master/convertedToIOS5/p560p575splitViewNoPopover/p560p575splitViewNoPopover/MySplitViewController.m

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/11/16/mail-app-style-split-view-controller-with-a-sliding-master-v.html

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for, very thorough.